# Can I add an Edit HTML button to a section?

Tags: themes, shopify

I’m working with the minimal theme and am trying to add an edit html button so that the html can be edited from the design panel (without going to the “edit code” area.

Specifically I want the button to be present in the rich text editor section (as it appears in other themes) but I would prefer to be able to add it to any section.

Is there a way I can do this using liquid? I can’t find anything in the docs.

Thanks!

Comment: not cleared, but tried to do

Comment: by "not cleared" do you mean that Shopify doesn't allow/encourage it? or that the question isn't clear? Thx

Comment: Any snapshot or something visual to understand it?